# How to correct errors found by Ghostscript in a PDF?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

When using Ghostscript (v9.56.1) to map the fonts in an old PDF to the fonts' current names on my system, I get an incomplete conversion product with some missing text. The PDF I'm working with is the manual found here: http://archives2.bungie.org/manuals/Trilogy_Manual.pdf.

My invocation is: `gs -sFONTMAP=/full/path/to/font-map.gs -sFONTPATH=/Users/admin/Library/Fonts -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o Trilogy_Manual-fixed.pdf Trilogy_Manual.pdf`

The .gs file contains:

```
/BankGothicBT-Medium /BankGothic-Medium ;
/ZapfDingbats /ZapfDingbatsITC ;
/Futura-ExtraBold /Futura-Bold ;
```

Most of the text does get properly remapped, however page numbers are omitted, and the full-page text on pages 22 and 58 of the PDF (pp. 20 and 56 by the manual's reckoning) which is in Bank Gothic Light goes missing as well.

I added the argument `-dPDFSTOPONERROR` to my invocation and got this output:

```
The following errors were encountered at least once while processing this file:
    error executing PDF token

The following warnings were encountered at least once while processing this file:
    encountered more q than Q
    invalid operator used in text block
    BT found inside a text block

   **** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
   **** The file was produced by: 
   **** >>>> Acrobat Distiller 3.0 for Power Macintosh <<<<
   **** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
   **** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
   **** specification.
```

I don't think the error is in the font remapping but rather in the PDF markup. Is there a way to correct these errors in the file? I'm a novice to working with PDFs.

Comment: Running the file with current code the only warnings are that the xref entries are not exactly 20 bytes. The fonts used by the PDF file are not embedded in the PDF file, so by running to pdfwrite you produce a new PDF file which will have the missing fonts replaced by substitutes. The substitute fonts will be those from your fontmap file. I don't have the fonts you are using so I cannot properly test this, and you haven't said which text is missing, but the output I get looks correct.

Comment: For now you can probably work around the problem by setting -dNEWPDF=false. The problem is almost certainly a bug which has been fixed. This is why we would appreciate people reporting bugs, if nobody reports them they won't get fixed. BTW you aren't 'remapping font names' here, you are creating a PDF file with embedded fonts which were not embedded in the original.

Comment: @KJ Yes, the missing fonts are the issue I'm trying to correct.  I am supplying new versions of Futura etc., and the fontmap.gs file points Ghostscript to those new copies of the fonts which have slightly different names than they did in 1997.  When a font is missing, Adobe products tend to replace it with AdobeSansMM, and the result in this case is terrible.

Comment: @KenS (Reply to your first comment) As far as which text is missing, see my sentence starting with "Most of the text does get properly remapped".  However it turns out that the missing text was a matter of Ghostscript disliking the copy of Futura that Apple supplied in macOS, and I was able to find another one that worked.  (To be clear on what I'm trying to do, I am in fact trying to create a new PDF for my own usage that has the embedded fonts.)

Comment: @KenS (Reply to your second comment) Using -dNEWPDF=false worked, thanks!  You mentioned reporting bugs — is there anything I can do to provide more information on this issue, or is there something which I should be filing a ticket for on the Ghostscript Bugzilla?  Just let me know.

Comment: I think the problems are already fixed, given that a debug build from the current tip of our Git repository doesn't show any of the problems you mention (it does say the xref entries are not technically correct, which is a common fault). So... I believe that the missing text is resolved, you shouldn't need to do anything more. That was more of a generic comment that it would really help us if people would report bugs when they find something wrong, not just ask here on Stack Overflow. I expect other Open Source developers have the same experience.

Comment: If you do find more problems then yes, please file a report on the GS Bugzilla, it may well be that it's already been fixed (we've been fixing problems with the new interpreter diligently for the last 4 months) but that just means we'll close it as 'worksforme' along with a thank you for the report.

Comment: @KenS Okay, I have noticed one or two other issues with the new interpreter when operating on some related PDFs, so I will report those.  I didn't want to file bugs unnecessarily so I asked this one on SO in case it was my fault or I could fix the PDF to solve the problem.  Edit: I take back what I said about Futura, GS *will* load the version that comes with macOS.  I must have been confusing this with some other issue I ran into.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run the command on Windows after installing the missing fonts but you should be able to do similar on other OS.
Image 1 is poor substitution in Edge even though the fonts were installed as shown in image 2. however after running GS

`gs[win64c] -sFONTPATH=c:\windows\fonts -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o Trilogy_Manual-fixed.pdf Trilogy_Manual.pdf`

the font is embedded correctly for Edge to then use it.

[image]

***Here I am double checking the embedment*** BEFORE & AFTER
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hmm, it appears that GS 9.56.1 *will* work using the new interpreter (which is on by default) if you do not supply a fontmap.  However for me in macOS, the correct fonts cannot be substituted in all places without using a fontmap.  For instance the word "FORGE" is not in Bank Gothic when I use your command.  And using the fontmap causes a bug to appear in GS' new interpreter, which was why KenS' advice to turn it off with "-dNEWPDF=false" was the correct solution for me.